# How can I show my extension's release note when it updates?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension, and I want to show **release note** when it update. Is there any **api**?

Answer (score 0):

You might use `window.showInformationMessage` to present a message to your users at initialization and guide them to an external web page link (or open a text file from your extension folder), but there isn't a VSCode API specific to release notes.